# Как взять несколько строк из MySQL для приложения Android/Java?

Tags: php, java, android, mysql, json

Пишу мобильное приложение на Android Studio (java), которое работает с mysql, находящемся на сервере, через файлы *.php на том же сервере. На MySQL есть таблица с колонками 'player1', 'player2', 'score' и т.д.

Мне нужно выбрать **несколько** строк с MySQL и передать в Android/Java, чтобы там их обрабатывать (создать рейтинг игроков - получить значения столбцов в разных строках). С одной строкой проблем нет, из мобильного приложения вызываю php файл на сервере, тот делает SELECT запрос к MySQL, возвращает одну строку и php файл передает ее в приложение через "echo $result", в приложении ловлю ее в `onPostExecute(AsyncTask)` через JSON. Но как в мобильном приложении Android получить и обрабатывать несколько строк из базы MySQL с одинаковыми полями/ключами?

Все что я пока придумал, получать в php JSON строки в одной переменной $array:

```
$mysql_qry = "SELECT * FROM t_waiting_for_game";
$result = $conn->query($mysql_qry);
$players = $result->fetch_assoc(MYSQL_BOTH);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $array = $array . json_encode($row);
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
echo $array;
```

Вообщем я понимаю, что в `$array` получается что-то такое:

```
{"gamenumber":"34","player1":"violka","player2":"fff","q1":"1"}
{"gamenumber":"40","player1":"123","player2":"qwe","q1":"2"}
```

Причем если обращаюсь к одному полю, дается значение только одной из строк, а не все, и как это все передать и обработать в java/android studio я не понимаю, гуглил всякое разное, но так чтоб что-то понял, не нашел, помогите пожалуйста!

Подскажите, как это сделать (выбрать несколько строк с MySQL и передать в Android/Java, чтобы там их обрабатывать и как их там обрабатывать)? Я начинающий, просьба объяснить как для тупого :)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, нельзя смешивать JSON и прямой вывод. Надо выбрать что-то одно. Если мы выбираем JSON, то никаких "0 results" наш код выдавать не должен. Надо как-то осилить вывод этой строки средствами андроид приложения.

Во-вторых, массив надо кодировать целиком, а не собирать его по кусочку как старушка, шьющая одеяло из обносков.

В-третьих, в коде не должно быть бессмысленных строк типа `$players = $result->fetch_assoc(MYSQL_BOTH);`

В-четвертых, хотя в mysqli и есть метод, который возвращает целиком массив, гарантировать его наличие нельзя. И поэтому надо использовать PDO:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM t_waiting_for_game")-fetchAll();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

     // output data of each row

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     $array[] = $row;

     }

} else {

     echo "0 results";

}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы, часть с php понял, java проблемы - на android/java я понимаю идут данные в таком формате

[{"gamenumber":"34","player1":"violka","player2":"fff},{"gamenumber":"40","player1":"123","player2":"qwe",}]

Как дальше с ними работать (получить два разных значения по ключу "player1"? Я пробую так, не без результата (playerName остается с начальным значением)

```
    String playerName = "fail";
    try {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = json_data.getJSONArray("player1");
        playerName = jsonArray.getString(1); // так playerName остается "fail"

        JSONObject line = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
        playerName = line.toString(); // и так playerName остается "fail"
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    alertDialog.setMessage(playerName);
    alertDialog.show();
```